# Salesforce for Slack App integration with one single user

Tags: workflow, slack, slack-salesforce-app

If there alternative way to everyone in slack to use single salesforce user? I want to trigger salesforce flow from slack only using single user in salesforce?
Open to any crazy idea (except api :) )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem, you see, i have an ORG with a lot of Platform Users.  They have access to Salesforce on some custom objects, but cannot connect their users with Slack, because they are not allowed on Sales Cloud for Slack.